# How to Recieve data with terminal in PHP language?

Tags: php

I want to receive some data as a .TXT file . Something like this :

```
terminal@root:~$ php myfile.php data.txt
```

How can I do that ? I searched. But nothing was useful about this.

Comment: You need to get the result of the php file inside the data.txt ? like php myfile.php > data.txt Or you need to use the data.txt as an argument ? you might use $_GET for this : php myfile.php?target=data.txt and use $_GET['target'] inside the php file to write (fopen, then fputs) in the file.

Comment: I actually want to receive the a.TXT and sava it as a variable. Then use it . please help me !

Comment: ok, so user $argv as suggested by ryrysv or $_GET array to have the filename as a variable, then you just have to open it and read it (like $f= fopen('data.txt','r'); $line = fgets($f);)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

and then read file by, ex:
     file_get_contents($file_name)

Answer (score 0):

In myfile.php, write a line liks this: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
Then call your script with a parameter "data.txt" as you mentioned.
The phpinfo function will output detailed information about the runtime. You will find several ways how you can access the parameter value.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a PHP beginner . Please explain with an example or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read about stream (stdin)
http://php.net/manual/fr/features.commandline.io-streams.php

And use command like  php myfile.php < data.txt or cat data.txt | php myfile.php

Your command gives an argument to myfile.php
Then you can handle this args with $argc and $argv[]

http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.argv.php